# get activity background color

Tags: android, android-layout

How to get activity background color?
When I'm using

```
//View activityLayout = getActivityLayout();
((PaintDrawable) activityLayout.getBackground()).getPaint().getColor();
```

I get exception: ColorDrawable cannot be cast to PainrDrawable.

Comment: So why are you trying to cast it into PaintDrawable?

Comment: I solved it.

    ColorDrawable colorDrawable = (ColorDrawable) activityLayout.getBackground();
    int color = colorDrawable.getColor();

Answer (score 1):

1st get the handler of the activity 
Get a handle to the root layout used, then set the background color on that. The root layout is whatever you called `setContentView` with.

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);

  // Now get a handle to any View contained 
  // within the main layout you are using
  View someView = findViewById(R.id.randomViewInMainLayout);

  // Find the root view
  View root = someView.getRootView()

  // Set the color
  root.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.red);
```

or you can use this in your activity

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```